# How to match patterns in with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i want to to validate a string if contains only a-z, 0-9, and the symbols . - _ @ and ;
i have this code:

```
var regex = new RegExp('[a-z0-9@.;_-]{8,}');
```

and is not far from what i am looking for but it return true also for:

'123@123.com   °%'

I'm working with jquery to load the string by a div, i put a some code more:

```
    var mailinglist= $('#mailinglist').val();
    var regex = new RegExp('\^[0-9a-z.-_;@]{8,}$\','i');

    if (mailinglist.match(regex)){}
    else{}
```

i need the match to return false if is present a blank space or any other char not defined in the pattern.

thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found here on  stackoverflow, i had to search better

[How to validate input using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344319/how-to-validate-input-using-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

Add the start- and end-of-string anchors.

```
var regex = /^[a-z0-9@.;_-]{8,}$/
//           ↑                 ↑
```

Also, unless you have some dynamic pattern, prefer the regex literal `/.../` over constructing a RegExp object from string `new RegExp('...')`.

Comment: How many dupes on this `^…$` issue has there been now? One of these days I'd hope to be the lucky one to land one of these...

Comment: @TrustWeb: `var regex = /^[a-z0-9@.;_-]{8,}$/;` itself is already a valid statement! **Do not** use `new RegExp`!

Comment: ...and the delimiters are supposed to be *forward* slashes, not backslashes.