# making certain inputs on a form required when a certain radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I have an input form for my users which starts with 3 radio buttons. These radio buttons look like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="customer" id="customer" value="A customer">Customer<br>
<input type="radio" name="customer" id="client" value="A client">Customer<br>
<input type="radio" name="customer" id="other" value="Other">Customer<br>
```

I then have 7 different input fields, one of the inputs is:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno">
```

I then have a "submit" button formatted as follows:

```
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

If for example a user selects 'Customer' then I want certain inputs to be set to a 'required' value (such as referenceno), so if those fields are not entered then the user cannot press login without entering the correct information.

Comment: Even though this is not an exact duplicate, you might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344319/how-to-validate-input-using-javascript) - and further - since it has all the answers you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onchange of the radio button select the input using document.querySelector and using setAttribute set the required attribute to the elements

```js
function a()
{
document.querySelector('.one').setAttribute('required','required');
document.querySelector('.five').setAttribute('required','required');

}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="customer" id="customer" onchange='a()' value="A customer">Customer<br>
<input type="radio" name="customer" id="client" value="A client">Customer<br>
<input type="radio" name="customer" id="other" value="Other">Customer<br>


<input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class='one'>
<input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class='2'>
<input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class='3'>
<input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class='4'>
<input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class='five'>
<input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class='5'>
<input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class='7'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to the input elements by matching the id of the radio button. Then on clicking on the button add the *required* attribute with that class name:

```js
var radio = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name=customer]'));
radio.forEach(function(r){
  r.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var allInput = document.querySelectorAll('[type="text"]');
    [].slice.call(allInput).forEach(function(el){
      el.required = false;
    });
    document.querySelector('.'+this.id).required = true;
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="customer" id="customer" value="A customer">Customer<br>
  <input type="radio" name="customer" id="client" value="A client">Customer<br>
  <input type="radio" name="customer" id="other" value="Other">Customer<br>

  <input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class="customer">
  <input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class="client">
  <input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class="other">

  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="radio" name="customer" id="customer" value="A customer">Customer<br>
  <input type="radio" name="customer" id="client" value="A client">Client<br>
  <input type="radio" name="customer" id="other" value="Other">Other<br>

  <input type="text" placeholder="reference no" name="referenceno">
  <input type="text" placeholder="other field" name="other-field">

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
let selectedCustomer = null;

const onCustomerSelected = (value) => {
  if (selectedCustomer === value) {
    return;
  }
  selectedCustomer = value;
  updateOnCustomerChanged();
};

const updateOnCustomerChanged = () => {
  const referenceNoInputField = document.querySelector('input[name=referenceno]');
  referenceNoInputField.required = selectedCustomer === 'A customer';
};

document.querySelectorAll('[name=customer]')
  .forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('change', () => {
      onCustomerSelected(el.value);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="container_id">
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="customer" id="customer" value="A customer">Customer<br>
  <input type="radio" name="customer" id="client" value="A client">Customer<br>
  <input type="radio" name="customer" id="other" value="Other">Customer<br>

  <input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class="customer">
  <input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class="client">
  <input type="text" placeholder="bla bla" name="referenceno" class="other">

  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
<script>
    var radio = document.querySelectorAll('[name=customer]');
  radio.forEach(function(r){
  r.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].required = false;
    }
    document.querySelector('.'+this.id).required = true;
  });
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```